# Error with helm-config

Tags: helm

Suddenly, I'm getting the error `"No such file or directory" "helm-config"` when I start Emacs. Here's what I have in my `config.org` which is called by `init.el`

```
(use-package helm
    :ensure t
    :bind
    ("C-x C-f" . 'helm-find-files)
    ("C-x C-b" . 'helm-buffers-list)
    ("M-x" . 'helm-M-x)
    :config
    (defun daedreth/helm-hide-minibuffer ()
      (when (with-helm-buffer helm-echo-input-in-header-line)
        (let ((ov (make-overlay (point-min) (point-max) nil nil t)))
          (overlay-put ov 'window (selected-window))
          (overlay-put ov 'face
                       (let ((bg-color (face-background 'default nil)))
                         `(:background ,bg-color :foreground ,bg-color)))
          (setq-local cursor-type nil))))
    (add-hook 'helm-minibuffer-set-up-hook 'daedreth/helm-hide-minibuffer)
    (setq helm-autoresize-max-height 0
          helm-autoresize-min-height 40
          helm-M-x-fuzzy-match t
          helm-buffers-fuzzy-matching t
          helm-recentf-fuzzy-match t
          helm-semantic-fuzzy-match t
          helm-imenu-fuzzy-match t
          helm-split-window-in-side-p nil
          helm-move-to-line-cycle-in-source nil
          helm-ff-search-library-in-sexp t
          helm-scroll-amount 8 
          helm-echo-input-in-header-line t)
    :init
    (helm-mode 1))


  (require 'helm-config)
  (helm-autoresize-mode 1)
  (define-key helm-find-files-map (kbd "C-b") 'helm-find-files-up-one-level)
  (define-key helm-find-files-map (kbd "C-f") 'helm-execute-persistent-action)
```

This popped up upon recent restart -- and I can't think of anything I've changed. So when I comment out the `(require 'helm-config)` things seem to go back to normal. Any ideas what this is about?

Comment: Check your `load-path` and make sure that the directory where `helm-config.el` lives is accessible.

Comment: Maybe the mystery is solved: Checking https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm I see a commit comment "Delete helm-config file no more useful" attached to emac-helm.sh. And no, there is no more helm-config.el in my elpa/20221212.628 but there was in older backup versions I have. So just comment it out. Life is good.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this, yesterday.  As suggested in the comments, removing `(require 'helm-config)` resolved the issue.